# Attempt to get HTML from website using PHP cURL does not work

Tags: php

I am attempting to write a script that can retrieve the HTML from my school's schedule search webpage. I am able to visit the web page normally when I visit it using a browser, but when I try to get it to work using cURL, it gets the HTML from the redirected page. When I changed the

```
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION
```

variable from true to false, it only outputs a blank page with the headers sent.

For reference, my PHP code is

```
<?php
$curl_connection = curl_init('https://www.registrar.usf.edu/ssearch/');

curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://www.registrar.usf.edu/");

$result = curl_exec($curl_connection);

print $result;

?>
```

The website that I am trying to get the HTML of from cURL is https://www.registrar.usf.edu/ssearch/ or https://www.registrar.usf.edu/ssearch/search.php

Any ideas?

Comment: The page is pushing a couple of cookies:  cookie_test=cookie_set; PHPSESSID=nijdlbfqe2dfqqege40eh7lai4

Comment: Should I get cURL to accept cookies and see if that works?

Comment: @cacidol - Yes, you should. Added an answer already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added 2 lines more, which now saves cookies which decides whether to redirect you when you try scraping the shedule's page.

```
$curl_connection = curl_init();
$url = "https://www.registrar.usf.edu/ssearch/search.php";
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt ($curl_connection, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');//cookiejar to dump cookie infos.
curl_setopt ($curl_connection, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');//cookie file for further reference from the site
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://www.registrar.usf.edu/");
$result = curl_exec($curl_connection);
echo $result;
```

Also, I havent seen anyone putting urls in `curl_init` yet.

Here is the cookie :

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

www.registrar.usf.edu   FALSE   /   FALSE   0   PHPSESSID   eied78t0v1qlqcop0rdk214361
www.registrar.usf.edu   FALSE   /ssearch/   FALSE   1336718465  cookie_test cookie_set
```

If you ever wanna debug a non working curl stuff, start with `var_dump(curl_getinfo($curl_connection));` and next one to check is  `curl_error($curl_connection);`

Comment: Great, that works, thanks! I looked at my cookie file but it doesn't look like it's written anything. I guess the website is looking that I can accept cookies but doesn't need them for anything useful. Do you think it's weird that it redirects to the main page instead of asking to accept cookies?

Comment: Its moreover like, if the site cant read the cookies back from us, redirect to home. So even if we save cookies, if we remove `curlopt_cookiefile` from where the site reads the cookie, it will redirect us to home.

Maybe, your uni needs protection for people who hate cookies :D